# check_mk "State and count of processes" rule threshold values

Tags: monitoring, nrpe, check-mk

I'm trying to turn a Nagios-NRPE check into a Check_MK one. The first one is:

```
check_procs -w 10 -c 15 -C crond
```

My attempt is to use the **`State and coung processes`** rule but it always raise a critical alert. The parameters of my rule are (extracted from the `rules.mk` configuration file):

```
'process': 'crond'
'okmax':   10
'okmin':    1
'warnmax': 15
'warnmin': 11
```

As the WATO config screen says nothing about critical thresholds, I have guessed the values outside these thresholds above raise a critical alert.

My problem is: when this rule is active, **an critical alert is raised even when the number of processes found is inside the OK threshold**.

The `Status detail` of the alert is

```
CRIT - 7 processes (ok from 1 to 15)CRIT 1620.6 MB virtual, 28.2 MB resident, 2.7% CPU
```

Then, I cannot understand this behaviour and I feel that I misunderstand the check_MK threshold parameters or I'm missing something.

Can you help me?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected in my question last paragraph, I misunderstood the check_MK threshold parametes.

These are the python code lines found in `~/share/check_mk/checks/ps`:

```
state = 0
if count > params["warnmax"] or count < params["warnmin"]:
    state = 2
    infotext += " (ok from %d to %d)(!!)" % (params["okmin"], params["okmax"])
elif count > params["okmax"] or count < params["okmin"]:
    state = 1
    infotext += " (ok from %d to %d)(!)" % (params["okmin"], params["okmax"])
```

So any value lower than **`warnmin`** raises a critical alert. Thus, in order to prevent this, the **`warn`** [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) must include the **`ok`** one. In my example, the **`warmin`** value should be lowered down to match the **`okmin`** one.

```
'process': 'crond'
'okmax':   10
'okmin':    1
'warnmax': 15
'warnmin':  1
```

In mathematical terms, the **`ok`** interval must be a subinterval of **`warn`** one.

I wrongly guessed these intervals should not overlap, but actually they must.